# Convert contents of UICollectionView to an Image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need convert the contents of an `UICollectionView` into an `UIIImage`. But, the image only contains the visible portion of the `UICollectionView` and leaves out the parts which are yet to be rendered. Is there any that I can achieve it ?

I am using the following extension

```
func toImage() -> UIImage {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size)
    return renderer.image { ctx in
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I  don't think so, because that content is not created yet.

Comment: You can't capture those cells which are not visible because `collectionView` reuse the cells and doesn't have all the cells at once. You will have to capture it one by one. Capture first screen then scroll one page without animation then capture next screen and so on... at last merge these images into single image and set back the `collectionView` y position.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any that I can achieve it ?

No, at least not by a simple screen capture. The offscreen cells do not even exist, so there is nothing for you to capture.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why your full Collection View is not rendered as an Image.

1. You call drawHierarchy in `self.bounds`, which will only capture the content in the specified bounds
2. The rest of the collection view will not be rendered as the rest of the cells will be off screen.